# how can i pass form input to a controller for log in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parse-platform

hello im using the `parse-ruby-client` gem and i want to be able to have a person who has an account with my database to log in with their credentials.

i created this form inside "home.html.erb":

```
% @page_title = "Log in" %>
<div class="Log_in_Form">
  <h1>Log in</h1>
  <%= form_for(:user, :url => {:controller => 'index', :action => 'home'}) do |f| %>
    <p> Username:</br> <%= f.text_field :username%> </p>
    <p> Password:</br> <%= f.password_field :password%></p>     
    <%= f.submit :Login %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

this is my controller "index_controller.rb"

```
class IndexController < ApplicationController
  def home
    user = Parse::User.authenticate(params[:username],params[:password])

  end
end
```

What i want to know how to do is pass the input from username and password over to the controller.

Answer (score 2):

The form params should be accessible through the `params[:user]` (since you have `form_for(:user)`):

```
def home
  user = Parse::User.authenticate(
    params[:user][:username], params[:user][:password]
  )
end
```

Comment: dont i have to do some routes too? for when i click the log in button?